# Ho to set a maximum bar chart height in ext js column charts?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

i'm using items with x, y position to display the sub title of a chart.
But bar height is over lapping the title how to set a default maximum bar height here

Comment: Can you please show some code. Check this link where you  can use bar height : http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.chart.series.Bar.html

Comment: iam using ext js 4.2.0 {
                 type  : 'text',
                 text  : "chartTitle",// displaying title
                 font  : '15px Helvetica',
                 width : 300,
                 height: 20,
                 x : 35, // the sprite x position
                 y : 10  // the sprite y position
             } my bar height is overlapping with this title

Comment: renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) 
    {
     if(attr.height>=27)
     {
       attr.height=attr.height-27;
       attr.y=attr.y+27;
     }
     } By using this code we can set maximum height of bar is it correct???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) 
{ 
 if(attr.height>=27)
      { 
       attr.height=attr.height-27;
       attr.y=attr.y+27; 
      }
 } 
//By using this code we can set maximum height of bar is it correct
```